# Declaring Injection fields as static

Tags: java, cdi, inject

Can I declare a Service injection as static in my Controller?

For example :

@Inject
    private static UserAttributeService userService;

Update : My requirement was to initialize a Map in static block. The map will be unmodifiable, but it will be initialized after a database call.

But its not being allowed as non static Service layer cannot be called from static block. I havent tried declaring my Service injection as static as I am not sure if its a good practice.

`static {
 crudService.executeNamedQuery(DBOperation.SELECT, "someQuery", null, null);
}`

Comment: Two follow-up questions:  1) Why do this if you're capable of injecting the dependency where you actually need it?  2)  Have you attempted this?

Comment: @Makoto Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

From the [annotation's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) :

> May apply to static as well as instance members.